# Django fields taking value of model-class

Tags: django, django-models

So I have two models `Transaction` and `Update`, which record transactions and updates of some objects. Then I want to have a table `Timeline`, which basically record the `pk` value of either a `transaction` or `update` and the `time_updated`. So I imagine such a `Timeline` table

```
class Timeline
    model = <taking value of type of model: Transaction or Update, etc.>
    identifing_num = models.CharField(...)
    time_updated = models.DatetimeField(...)
```

What I want to achieve is simple, just to keep a time-ordered record of all other actually-meaningful records. I can of course query the two models (`Transaction` and `Update`), do a `mergesort`, and get a time-ordered `queryset`, but just curious if this `Timeline` thing can be written down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Or add two ForeignKeys to `Transaction` and `Update` with `null=True`.  Concrete model could be accessed via property:

```
class TimeLine(models.Model):

    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, null=True)
    update = models.ForeignKey(Update, null=True)
    identifing_num = models.CharField(...)
    time_updated = models.DatetimeField(...)

    @property
    def model(self):
        return self.transaction or self.update
```